# "Turn display off after" setting is not saved

Tags: sleep-wake, kernel-panic

I have a 16" Macbook Pro which is suffering from a [common bug that causes it to kernel panic every time it sleeps](https://mrmacintosh.com/10-15-4-update-wake-from-sleep-kernel-panic-in-16-mbpro-2019/). Until Apple fixes this (presuming they actually do), I am trying to work around it by telling the Mac not to sleep while plugged in:

[image: sleep]

However, every time I restart my computer (because I have to unplug it sometimes and then it sleeps and crashes), it forgets this setting and resets it to 5 minutes! Why isn't this setting saved?

I'm using MacOS 10.15.5.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with resetting the SMC and NVRAM on your system -- If I recall a lot of the sleep settings are in one of the two -- likely SMC.

**To reset SMC:** https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

**To reset NVRAM:** Shut down computer. Hold Apple, Option, P, R on keyboard as you power on -- keep holding until you hear the startup chime a second time and let go.
Typically I use my left hand to get Apple, Option, P. Then right hand to press power and quickly get the R held down.

Answer (score 0):

For me I need drag the slider to the target minutes, but click to set not work.